# Memory leak in CardboardActivity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, google-cardboard

While profiling my Google Cardboard application, I found out a very large memory leak (15Mb!) each time I left the activity with the 3D graphics.

After a long and grievous investigation, I found out that the source of the problem was a [Context leak](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) that happened each time I closed my `CardboardActivity` subclass.

The solution can be found in the accepted answer`*`

`*` wow... this is awkward... Note for any kind (and *experienced*) reviewer: I am writing a question to whom I know the answer already: am I supposed to do something for style, like add some fake suspense (*"will our heroes prevail?! Find out in the accepted answer!"*), like in a old Batman TV series or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After dicing and slicing my `CardboardActivity` subclass, until nothing else but the base class remained, I had to conclude that the base class itself was leaking the context.

I searched the web and found [this post](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-java/issues/19) explaining how the activity in question leaked the context by failing to un-register a listener with a private instance of a class.

Upon trying to invoke said method manually (using reflection), I found out that in the current version of the Cardboard SDK (0.5.4 at the time of writing), the field is not present anymore.

Long story short: all sensors are now handled by an undocumented (yet public) [SensorConnection](https://github.com/danthemellowman/ofxCardboard/blob/master/cardboard.src%202/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/sensors/SensorConnection.java) class instantiated in `CardboardActivity` as a `sensorConnection` field, which is still plagued by the bug detailed in my first link.

This led me to this solution:

- get the `sensorConnection` field in the `CardboardActivity` by reflection
- use it to get the `magneticSensor` field, again by reflection
- invoke the `setOnCardboardTheaterListener` with `null` argument, to clear the binding holding the reference to the `Context` in the `Activity` `onDestroy` method.

this boils down to the following code:

```
private void workAroundLeak() {
    try {
        // Get the sensor Connection
        Class<?> c1 = Class.forName("com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardActivity");
        Field sensorsField = c1.getDeclaredField("sensorConnection");
        sensorsField.setAccessible(true);
        SensorConnection sc = (SensorConnection) sensorsField.get(this);
        if(sc == null) return;

        // Get the magnetSensor
        Class<?> c2 = Class.forName("com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.sensors.SensorConnection");
        Field magnetField = c2.getDeclaredField("magnetSensor");
        magnetField.setAccessible(true);
        MagnetSensor ms = (MagnetSensor) magnetField.get(sc);
        if(ms == null) return;

        ms.setOnCardboardTriggerListener(null);
    } catch(Exception e) {}
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    workAroundLeak();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

which solved the problem entirely.

**A word to the wise**: since this solution relies on reflection, it might break (without consequences other than doing nothing, likely) as soon as Google will update the SDK (possibly fixing the issue in a clean way).

Hope this helps someone